# Runtime instantiation of template class

Tags: c++, templates

I've this template class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept StringLike = std::convertible_to<T, std::wstring_view> || std::convertible_to<T, std::string_view>;

enum class SinkType : uint8_t
{
    Console,
    File
};

template<SinkType Sink>
class Logger
{
public:
    Logger() = delete;
    Logger(const std::string& logDir, const std::string& fileLogLevel, size_t newMaxSize = 0, size_t newMaxFiles = 0);

    template <StringLike S>
    void Log(const S& msg) const;

    // ...
}
```

that depending on the `SinkType` will log the message either to some file or stdout.

My problem comes when I need to instantiate that since the choice is taken at runtime, i.e. reading from a json file which approach to use.

Is there any way to instantiate it with something like this:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<utility::Logger<sinkType>> coreLogger{ new utility::Logger<sinkType>{ currentDir, reqLogLevel, maxSizeLogLevel, maxNumberLogs } };
```

where `sinkType` is not a `constexpr` since I'm reading it from file? Changing from static to dynamic polymorphism should do the trick but I would lose the ability to constraint `Log` function via concepts. The solution should be something like this:

```cpp
class StandardLogger
{
public:
 StandardLogger() = delete;
 virtual ~StandardLogger() = default;

 virtual void Log(const std::string& msg) const = 0

protected:
 auto pattern() const noexcept -> const std::string& { return pattern_; }

private:
 const std::string pattern_{ "[%Y-%m-%d %T.%e%z] [%l] %v" }; 
}

class FileLogger : public StandardLogger
{
public:
    FileLogger () = delete;
    FileLogger (const std::string& logDir, const std::string& fileLogLevel, size_t newMaxSize = 0, size_t newMaxFiles = 0);

    virtual void Log(const std::string& msg) const override;
    // ...
}

class ConsoleLogger : public StandardLogger
{
public:
    ConsoleLogger () = delete;
    explicit ConsoleLogger (const std::string& fileLogLevel);

    virtual void Log(const std::string& msg) const override;
    // ...
}
```

I would like to know if there is some hackish-stuff that I can use to continue with the first approach - since I would like also to keep concepts on `Log` function, and if it is `virtual` I can't.

Comment: `std::variant<Logger<Console>,Logger<File>>`?

Comment: @user17732522 I tried right now but I'm not able to extract logger object from `std::variant` once returned. I can't do `std::get<Logger<?>>(variantResult)` since at compile time I don't known which type it is.

Comment: Yes, you need to access it via `std::visit` if you don't know the actual type. I am not sure what your goal here is in the end. If you want `Log` to be a template constrained by concepts, then you need to know the actual type at compile-time so that the concept can be checked at compile-time or you need to map over all possible types (which is what `std::visit` does).

Comment: @user17732522  I would like to pass both `std::string` and `std::wstring` types. I never used `std::visit`before but I found [something](https://www.cppstories.com/2020/04/variant-virtual-polymorphism.html/) that should work for me. So in my case should I have a struct foreach public callable method of my loggers with an overloaded callable operator for each class (i.e. `Logger<Console>` and `Logger<File>`) and for each suitable parameter type that satisfies my constraint? Oh dear...
Would you suggest to move to dynamic polymorphism and drop the concepts? It's look like cumbersome for me.

Comment: If you want to support only two specific types, then go with polymorphism via inheritance and simply use two `virtual` functions. Please update your question with code that actually demonstrates the issues you want to avoid. You hide all the important part in the last half-sentence.

Comment: @user17732522 I updated the initial code with the requirement on the constraint, thank you. In case of multiple types to handle, `std::visit` remains the only way to go?

Comment: For what you are showing you can also just have `Log` be a template in the base class forwarding to a private `virtual` function with the actual implementation. That `virtual` function needs to know only about the converted type, so there need to be only two overloads for it.